# Якорные ссылки не работают в React с HashRouter на gh-pages

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, github-pages

Я использую HashRouter gh-pages. Из-за этого якорные ссылки не работают и меня перенаправляет на страницу 404.

**роутинг**

```
 <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/'>
              <Main />
            </Route>
            <Route path='*'>
              <NotFound />
            </Route>
    </Switch>
```

**компонент со списком якорных ссылок**

```
    export default function NavTab() {
        return (
            <ul
                className='navtab__link-list'
            >
                        <li
                        >
                            <a href={'#about-project'}
                                className='navtab__link'
                            >
                                О проекте
                            </a>
                        </li>
...
                    )
                })}
            </ul>
        )
    }
```

**компонент с якорной ссылкой**

```
export default function Techs() {
    return (
        <section className='about-project' id='#about-project'>
            <SectionTitle
            />
        </section>
    )
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: the code works well on localhost with ReactRouter